# How do I improve the performance of my SELECT query in Sqlite / Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm getting poor performance and possibly strange behavior with a simple SELECT query in Sqlite & Android. `SqliteDatabase.query()` executes my query in only 1 ms, but fetching the results with `Cursor.get*()` takes over 150 ms to return only 8 rows!

I am trying to find all the rows in the table `english` where the column `word` starts with "prefix" (an arbitrary string), sort the results by the `row` column, and return only the first 8 results.

Here is my code:

```
String columns[] = {"word", "rank"};
Cursor cursor = mDB.query("english", columns, "word LIKE '" + prefix + "%'", null, null, null, "rank,word", "8");

// It takes only 1 ms to get here

String word = "";
int rank = 0;
if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
    do {
        word = cursor.getString(0);
        rank = cursor.getInt(1);
    }
    while(cursor.moveToNext());
}

cursor.close();

// It takes over 150 ms to get here!
```

The table definition for `english` is:

```
CREATE TABLE en (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, word TEXT, rank INTEGER)
```

It contains about 65,000 entries. It also also indexes on `word` and `rank`, with a third index for both (I was getting desperate!):

```
CREATE INDEX "rank" ON "en" ("rank" ASC)
CREATE INDEX "word" ON "en" ("word" ASC)
CREATE INDEX "word_rank" ON "en" ("word" ASC, "rank" ASC)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query method doesn't actually retrieve all the data, the cursor retrieves it as it moves through the rows. So it makes sense that the Cursor.move*() methods are slower then the query.

This 'lazy-loading' concept helps save memory as only the relevant data is retrieved as it's needed.

As for performance, you really aren't doing anything wrong. Are you trying this on the emulator? Perhaps try it on an actual device and test the performance.

Comment: Hi Kane. After I posted my question I discovered the bottleneck is cursor.moveToFirst(), which makes sense with what you said. I'm running it on an actual device but performance is critical because my app is an IME (soft keyboard) and the query is looking up dictionary matches so it must be faster than a keystroke. 150+ ms is just too slow. :(

Comment: Barry, 150ms is only too slow if you are performing the query on the UI thread. You should definitely be looking at moving the database operations onto a separate thread and then posting the results back to the UI thread to update the list. For information about this technique have a read of this http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: I thought about that but there is a synchronization problem if the user presses the space bar before the lookup thread finds his word: the auto-select feature will insert the wrong word. However I'll take another look at that approach anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Just check for that condition before updating the UI. i.e. Keep a record of the search used to find the rows and then if the text box has changed by the time the data gets to the UI ignore it.

Comment: I cannot ignore late data because it can -- and often will -- contain the completion or correction of the word the user was typing. The previous lookup is more likely to contain an incorrect completion since the user hadn't finished typing the word. Dictionary suggestions must appear in real-time as the user is typing. Doing the lookup on the UI thread avoids this problem (but causes others). I'll experiment with lookup threads but synchronization with the UI will have to be very robust.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean now, What I would do is drop SQLite as the database and implement a storage system which uses a tree and would be much more efficient at looking up words based on their first few letters.

Comment: That's what I'm already doing and the performance is very good. So why am I asking questions about sqlite? Because my implementation is read-only and now I need read/write and adding that functionality would be a major headache so I am exploring alternatives. I realize now the reason my database is so much faster (2 ms lookup vs. 150 ms) is because my database is in-memory and sqlite is not. In-memory sqlite might be the answer (if it exists) but I'll save that for another question. Thank you, Kane! :)